# Fatal Error: main() Cannot write properly in dir/dir/dir/dir

Tags: php

I just recently created this little piece of code, altrought its pulling me the error you can see in the title.
This is the code..

```
<?php if($comment_count->num_rows = 0)
        echo '<div class="CenterText"><p>No Comments Yet</p></div>';
```

`$comment_count` variable -

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$comment_count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = '$id'");
```

`$db` variable-

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','--','pw','--') or die('error with connection');
?>
```

This is probably something really stupidly small, But I can't find the reasoning for it. Thanks for help!

Comment: There's not enough here to comment. Post a snippet of code that shows how these various lines relate to each other, and includes the line where the error appears. Post the complete error message too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IF condition has assignment operator instead of equality operator.

change

```
<?php if($comment_count->num_rows = 0)
```

to

```
<?php if($comment_count->num_rows == 0)
```

May be this is the issue? Try it.